# Get user that created a message ruby on rails mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I'm trying a query to get the user that created a message in a specific sala but I can't find the way.
I've got the query to get the messages of the specific sala, but I can't get the user that created the message.

Mensajes_controller (where I get the messages from the sala)

```
def index
    @mensaje = @sala.mensajes.desc('_id').limit(20)
    render json: @mensaje
end
```

set_sala (to get the room from which I want the messages)

```
def set_sala
  if params[:sala_id]
    @sala = Sala.find(params[:sala_id])
  end
end
```

mensaje model

```
class Mensaje
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps::Created

      field :cuerpo, type: String

      validates :cuerpo, presence: true

      belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :user_id
      belongs_to :sala, foreign_key: :sala_id

end
```

user model

```
class User
    include Mongoid::Document
    include ActiveModel::SecurePassword

      has_secure_password
      field :password_digest, type: String
      field :email, type: String
      field :nombre, type: String

      has_many :salas
      has_many :mensajes

      validates :nombre, presence: true
      validates :email, presence: true
      validates :password_digest, presence: true

end
```

Updating - Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.5.5'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.3'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.12'
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
gem 'mongoid-bcrypt-ruby'

gem 'devise'

gem 'kaminari-mongoid'
gem 'mongo'
# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

gem 'mongoid', '~> 7.0.5'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

# Use Rack CORS for handling Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS), making cross-origin AJAX possible
gem 'rack-cors'

gem 'jwt_sessions', '~> 2.3'
gem 'mongoid-rspec', github: 'mongoid/mongoid-rspec', ref: '68c95b133be1a1482fe882e39afd33262147d1f4'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'factory_bot_rails'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
end

group :development do
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end


# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Feel free to ask anything you may need. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```rb
@mensaje.user
```

and install kaminari-mongoid and maybe mongo gem.

Comment: This is the error that throws when I try that: NoMethodError (undefined method `user' for #<Mongoid::Criteria:0x000055605c2913e8>)

Comment: Attach Gemfile to your question pls

Comment: When you try `@mensaje.user` , before you create `@mensaje` as `@mensaje = @sala.mensajes.desc('_id').limit(20)`?

Comment: It throws this error: NoMethodError (undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass):

Comment: Try `Mensaje.last.user`

Comment: `NoMethodError (undefined method user for nil:NilClass)`? Are you sure you have at least one object of this model? Check pls `Mensaje.all`

Comment: That worked! So first, how should I control if the objects are not nill when I first access it? I have another question, now I have to render both @ user and @ message, how should I do this to access in the front?

Comment: Good. 
You can use `@mensaje.nil?` for check.
Last question I don't understood(
psl upvote my solution, and mark mine as the right decision)

Comment: What do you mean by `how should I do this to access in the front?`

Comment: I'm using Vuejs as frontend. What is the best way to render both objects, @ user and @mensajes to be accesible in the front? I've tried a solution but I only can access the user

Comment: Create something like this `users/:id/mensajes/`.